# Find categories list for a blog

Tags: 2007, blog

I am developing a webpart related to blogs and is there any way to fetch the categories list url for that particular blog?

Answer (score 1):

Categories for a blog are just stored in a list for that blog. You can use a Data View Web Part or calls to the object model to pluck them out like any other list. If you're looking to aggregate categories across multiple blogs, then use the Content Query web part or the SPQuery class to do a query in code (CAML).

Answer (score 1):

If your blog is in this url for example:

http://site/blogs/blog

Then your categories will probably be in

http://site/blogs/Lists/categories

I believe it will always have the same name if you use the Blog site template.